Converting pipe-separated file containing GeoJSON geometries to GeoJSON with ogr2ogr
I have a pipe-separated file, src.psv:
col0|col1|geom
123|abc|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[12,34]}
456|xyz|{"type":"Point","coordinates":[56,78]}

I would like to convert it to a GeoJSON using ogr2ogr. The output I am for is this dst.geojson:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "src",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "123", "col1": "abc" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12, 34 ] } },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "456", "col1": "xyz" }, "geometry": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 56, 78 ] } }
]
}

I believe I have to use the CSV driver, in particular the SEPARATOR field:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" dst.geojson src.psv -oo SEPARATOR=PIPE

However, quite unsurprisingly, doing the above does not result in the desired dst.geojson. Instead, dst.geojson is:
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "src",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "123", "col1": "abc", "geom": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 12, 34 ] } }, "geometry": null },
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "col0": "456", "col1": "xyz", "geom": { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 56, 78 ] } }, "geometry": null }
]
}

with "geometry": null for both features. I believe I should use the -sql option, but I don't know what query to write exactly so that I have the desired output. I think the query I am after has this form:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" -sql "SELECT WHAT_COMES_HERE?(geom) as geomery, col0, col1 from src" dst.geojson src.psv -oo SEPARATOR=PIPE

But I don't know what the WHAT_COMES_HERE? function is. Note that I should not assume that the entries in the geom fields are only Points, they could be any valid GeoJSON features.
How to convert a pipe-separated file containing GeoJSON geometries to a GeoJSON?

Can't try rn but looks to me like you want to explicitly specify the geometry column name to consider (geom -> geometry).

As geom is not the default name, you need to add -oo GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES=geom to tell ogr2ogr that the geometry is in the geom column: CSV driver: open options.
Something like this:
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" dst.geojson src.psv -oo SEPARATOR=PIPE -oo GEOM_POSSIBLE_NAMES=geom

